# error: no matching function for call to template function with vector reference

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to patch up some legacy code and found this error related to templates.

> error: no matching function for call to ‘Clause_new(vec&, bool)’ Clause* c = minisat::Clause_new(ps, false);

Clause_new is part of the following template:

```
    namespace minisat
    {
      class Clause {
      public:

         // NOTE: This constructor cannot be used directly (doesn't allocate enough memory).
         template<class V>
         Clause(V& ps, bool learnt) {...}

         template<class V>
         friend Clause* Clause_new(V& ps, bool learnt = false) {...};
    }}
```

And then Clause_new is called here:

```
bool Solver::addClause(vec<Lit>& ps)
{
     if (!ok)
        ...
     else{
         ... //ps can change here
     }

     if (ps.size() == 0)
         ...
     else if (ps.size() == 1){
         ...
     }else{
         Clause* c = minisat::Clause_new(ps, false);
         ...
     }   
     return true;
 }
```

I have already tried changing the declaration of ps to const (modifying the corresponding method declarations), but then I get this error:

> error: passing ‘const minisat::Lit’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive].

Comment: Nothing stick out at to me with this code.  Can you add a [mcve]?

Comment: What does compiler say when you point a type explicitly: `Clause* c = minisat::Clause_new<vec<Lit>>(ps, false);`?

Comment: Here you didn't print `;` after the class declaration but did it after the function definition. It is confusing.

Comment: Hmmm, the compiler says... nothing :) That worked. Thank you!

Comment: Edit: To be clear, the solution was Clause* c = minisat::Clause_new<vec<Lit>>(ps, false). If ilotXXI posts this in the solutions, I can confirm it.